# mysql query returning incorrect results with multiple LIKE expressions

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I am running this query

```
SELECT `contacts`.* 
FROM `contacts` 
WHERE 
    ((email NOT LIKE '%domain1%') AND 
     (email NOT LIKE '%domain2%') AND 
     (email NOT LIKE '%domain3%') AND 
     (email NOT LIKE '%domain4%')
    ) AND (
     DATE(created_at) = '2014-03-21'
    )
```

results is

```
 => [["ram.kumar@domain1.com", Fri, 21 Mar 2014 06:17:07 UTC +00:00],  
     ["ram.kumar@domain2.com", Fri, 21 Mar 2014 17:05:21 UTC +00:00]]
```

The problem

- result should exclude all rows with "domain1", "domain2" and so on... but it is not doing that

*PS: The query results is not shown as MySQL output as I am running it from rails console.*

```
Contact.external.created_on( Time.parse("2014-03-21 ")).collect {|e| [e.email, e.created_at]}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the query being run?  It should be doing what you expect and filtering out those four domains.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I recommend including the TLD in your domain, e.g. "domain1.com". Then you can use `SUBSTRING(email...)` instead of `LIKE`. I think this can boost the performance.

Comment: you can pull the actual query from your mysql.log file if you need to check it

Comment: yes @GordonLinoff, the query is running. That is why I am able to see the results. I know it should be doing that, but is not.

Comment: Thanks @RacilHilan, I cannot use TLD as I need eliminate multiple TLDs in one filter condition.

Comment: @ramonrails I see. Are all your TLDs 3 letters? Or do they vary in length?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `OR` conditions instead

```
SELECT `contacts`.* 
FROM `contacts` 
WHERE 
    (email NOT LIKE '%domain1%' OR
     email NOT LIKE '%domain2%' OR 
     email NOT LIKE '%domain3%' OR 
     email NOT LIKE '%domain4%'
    ) AND (
     DATE(created_at) = '2014-03-21'
    )
```

`"ram.kumar@domain1.com"` is not, `NOT LIKE '%domain4%'` if that makes sense

Comment: OR is going to select every row anyways. Am I right? `true OR false` will select every row.

Comment: @ramonrails . . . You are correct.  If it is like one of the patterns, then it is not like the others, so the `or` will always evaluate to true.